# iOS app crashes when displaying SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Okay, so I have a single view iOS app. Inside the view controller, I have a method attached to a button in the storyboard. Here is the method for when then button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)tweetButton:(id)sender {
  if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:@"SLServiceTypeTwitter"]) {
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:@"SLServiceTypeTwitter"];

    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"This is a test."];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"Twitter not configured.");
  }
}
```

Whenever I press the button in the app, I get a crash with the following error:

`2015-07-17 15:57:24.110 Now Playing[425:19583] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <ViewController: 0x157e4c620>.'`

My code follows pretty much every example that I have seen online, so I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: Use the macro variable for the service type, don't hard type them, replace `@"SLServiceTypeTwitter"` by `SLServiceTypeTwitter`

Comment: Duh! That worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't hard type the service type even if it's taking a `NSString`, you must use one of  the constant instead: `SLServiceTypeTwitter`, `SLServiceTypeFacebook`...

Also, `composeViewControllerForServiceType:` is already doing the alloc/init steps for you, so no need to allocate it before calling this method.

Code fixed:

```
- (IBAction)tweetButton:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"This is a test."];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Twitter not configured.");
    }
}
```